# std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x002b123c

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

I am making a small program. First I made a Header File:

```
private:

    string UserName, Password;
public:


    void setUN(string);
    void setP(string);

    string getUN();
```

Then in my cpp file:

```
    void UserInfo::setUN(string un){

    UserName = un;
}


    string UserInfo::getUN(){

    return UserName;
}
```

After that in my main I make a object:

```
UserInfo addUser[100];
```

to add users

```
cout<<"Enter Username : ";

    getline(cin,tUN);
    addUser[0].setUN(tUN);
```

After that in my other function void LoginScreen()

I made the same object:

```
UserInfo addUser[100];

string EUN, EP;
system("cls");
cout<<"Enter Username : ";
cin>>EUN;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Enter Password : ";
//cin>>EP;

for( int a = 0; a <= 100; a++){
    if (EUN == addUser[a].getUN()){
        system("cls");
        cout<<"OMG HELP MEEE ";
        break;
    }
}
```

It works fine when till get to this for loop and gives this error:

```
std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x002b123c
```

Can you tell me what the error means and how can I get rid of this.

Comment: A<=100 is the problem

Comment: well when I remove the for loop and use this instead
"if (EUN == addUser[0].getUN()) "
the if statement also  does not work.
@billz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UserInfo addUser[100];` has elements indexed from 0 - 99.

So fix:-

```
for( int a = 0; a <= 100; a++){
                ^^This should be a < 100
}
```